# Where is a dmg file mounted?

Tags: mount, dmg

When I double click a dmg file it's mounted (or so I assume) in the filesystem. I want to explore the dmg file in the terminal for hidden files (like the background for example), but I'm not sure where it's mounted - I checked /media and /mnt, but it's not there.

Comment: I don't use OSX, but can you not type `mount` in the terminal to see all mounted "volumes"

Comment: @user606723 Yes, you can use `mount`. It shows the volumes that are mounted, their mount points, how they're formatted, etc.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

All volumes, including DMGs, are mounted in `/Volumes`.

You can get a list of mounted volumes by typing `ls /Volumes` in Terminal.

You can navigate to a Disk Image using `cd /Volumes/nameOfImage`.

Comment: You can also drag files and folders from the Finder into a Terminal window, and it'll paste in their path(s).  This is an easy way to find out where something's mounted in the unix filesystem.

Comment: You can also drag them to the spotlight search box and it'll expand the full path there.

Comment: Actually, you can get a list of mounted volumes by typing `mount` in Terminal. Some volumes may be mounted outside of `/Volumes` (like FileVault) and not everything under `/Volumes` *has* to be a volume. (It should be, but sometimes normal directories get created under there)